# How to make user to keep in login state by using laravel's personal access token

Tags: laravel

I have implement my api by using personal access token with the 1 month validity by using below code.

```
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addMonths(1));
```

I can receive an unauthenticated error once the token gets expired. In this case, i have to extend the validity which mean the user should be in login state unless they do logout manually.

Is it possible to keep the user in login mode?. If it can, pls give detailed explanation.

Comment: They last, by default, a year. Is that not enough? Or set it to `now()->addYears(100)` and be fairly comfortable your website will go away before the tokens do.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thanks for your comment. But is this a standard way to extend the validity.

Answer (score 0):

I think Passport can refresh the token only with oauth; but don't get me wrong, probably you don't need oauth. So you should refresh it by yourself because Passport doesn't handle it. What I can suggest in case you are building a backend API for a web-app is to use Sanctum Spa-Authentication, it gives you csrf protection and is really easy to understand
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#spa-authentication.
Once you logged in you can call your api routes.
But if it's not a web-app even Sanctum has not a refresh token method...

Comment: Thanks for your response. We use it only for mobile app.